# To make a script as background process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, background

I need to run a script in background. I tried to run with methods like

./my-script &
Ctrl +z
bg

But I want to make the script directly run as a background process.
Can anyone help me??

Comment: Please look for nohup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write a wrapper script, which will call the actual script in background.
2. Good idea to log what that script sends to STDOUT/STDERR.
3. The script must not die, when you exit the terminal.

E.g. **my-wrapper-script.sh**:

```
<absolute_path>/my-script.sh > /<..path..>/my-script.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

use `screen`
This is how you can use it:

> > > `screen`
> > >
> > > `you_command`

now that your command it running you can do a `Ctrl+a` then `d`. `d` is to detach the terminal and run the process in background
to reattach your terminal use:

> > > `screen -list`

Get the socket number from the here, lets say is 63058. Then:

> > > `screen -r 63058`

To kill the screen use 
`ctrl + a`, then `k`